# How to get a unique set of node pairs for undirected relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple set of undirected relationships:

```
(p1)-[r:appears_in_same_doc]-(p2)
```

I would like to extract id(p1), id(p2) pairs from this. However, when I do the following:

```
MATCH (p1:person)-[r:appear_in_same_document]-(p2:person)
return id(p1), id(p2)
```

I get:

```
id(p1) | id(p2
-------+------
 1     |  2
 2     |  1
 1     |  3
 3     |  1
 etc.
```

That is, I get for each pair of nodes, both possibilities:

```
p1, p2 AND p2, p1
```

in the result set. This is undesired in the application I work on, but I cannot figure out how to get only half of the "possibilities". I.e.

```
id(p1) | id(p2
-------+------
 1     |  2
 1     |  3
 etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
MATCH (p1:person)-[r:appear_in_same_document]-(p2:person)
where id(p1) > id(p2)
return id(p1), id(p2)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. This is almost embarrassing. But yeah, that seems to do the trick.